# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. Laravel на IIS 7.5

Tags: .htaccess, laravel5, iis-7

Уже неделю пытаемся запустить проект Laravel 5 на IIS 7.5 сервере теперь упираемся в эту ошибку при переходе на главную страницу -

*This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.*

Суть проблемы в том что на сервере нет доступа к интернету, на IIS крутиться SharePoint 2010 и мы планируем запустить Laravel 5:)

Делали все по инструкциям, единственное, что отличалось это перенос с гита пустого проекта Laravel 5 а не установка через Composer и то, что везде в инструкциях устанавливается на чистый IIS а у нас уже на нем SharePoint.

Не знаю будет ли это полезной информацией, но на всякий случай...

Помогите пожалуйста разрешить эту проблему. Будем рады любой помощи.

Comment: Посмотрите к какому пулу приложений у вас привязывается ваша Laravel, грубо говоря нужно понять что использует IIS для запуска фреймворка Laravel

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то  в Application pool у меня установлено - DefaultAppPool и свойства его .Net Framework Version: 2.0 Pipeline mode: Integrated

Comment: https://jimfrenette.com/2016/09/laravel-iis-windows-install/

Comment: я делал как в http://www.q2w3.ru/2010/05/08/1673/ с разницей что установка php из zip архива и в принципе странца test.php у меня открывается через iis

Comment: с Вашей ссылки ставят через composer а у меня к сожалению такой возможности нет т.к. нет выхода в интернет на сервере и как предположение что файл web.config сгенерированный через url rewrite может быть неправильным